# Does the distance metric used with K-Medoids needs to respect the triangle inequality?

Tags: distance, k-medoids

I'd like to understand if the K-Medoids algorithm requires to be used with a distance metric that respects the triangle inequality. In particular I'd like to try to apply the K-Medoids algorithm with the CIEDE2000 color distance which I don't know if satisfies the triangle inequality.